# Is it possible to get the original field names of @JsonProperty?

Tags: java, spring, jackson, objectmapper

I need to create a map of @JsonProperty Values to Original field names.
 Is it possible to achieve?

My POJO class:

```
public class Contact
{
  @JsonProperty( "first_name" )
  @JsonView( ContactViews.CommonFields.class )
  private String firstName;

  @JsonProperty( "last_name" )
  @JsonView( ContactViews.CommonFields.class )
  private String lastName;

  public String getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }

  public void setFirstName( String firstName )
    {       
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

  public String getLastName()
    {
        return lastName;
    }

  public void setLastName( String lastName )
    {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

I need a map like:

```
{"first_name":"firstName","last_name":"lastName"}
```

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: You want to be able to map the jsonProperty value to the field name value, is that correct?

Comment: @dambros: Yes. Map of JsonProperty to FieldNames

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should do what you are looking for:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    Field[] fields = Contact.class.getDeclaredFields();

    for (Field field : fields) {
        if (field.isAnnotationPresent(JsonProperty.class)) {
            String annotationValue = field.getAnnotation(JsonProperty.class).value();
            map.put(annotationValue, field.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Using your Contact class as example, the output map will be:

```
{last_name=lastName, first_name=firstName}
```

Just keep in mind the above output is simply a `map.toString()`. For it to be a JSON, just convert the map to your needs.

Comment: Thanks! This was useful for me when I wanted to get the JsonProperty annotation on my enum, which is different than the raw enum value. `Field field = MyEnum.NAME.getClass().getField("NAME")`